# max_num_pages says 4, yet I am only able to navigate to the third page

Tags: wp-query, pagination

**Current query:**

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; }

$args_main = array(
    'cat'               => $my_categories_variable,
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'paged'             => $paged
);

$main_posts_query = new WP_Query($args_main);
while($main_posts_query->have_posts()) : $main_posts_query->the_post();
```

**Problem:** Echoing `echo $main_posts_query->max_num_pages;` gives me **4**, yet I am only able to navigate (via `get_next_posts_link()`) to www.mywebsite.com/page/**3**/.

Am I missing something? Please do let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning three different values to your variable:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') )
{
    $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
}
else if ( get_query_var('page') )
{
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
}
else
{
    $paged = 1;
}
```

Short explanation:

1. On `single.php`, `singular.php` and other single view templates: `(int) $page` Is the page of the post, as specified by the query var page: `get_query_var( 'page' );`
2. On all sorts of `archive.php` and similar archive/post type list view templates: `(int) $paged` Is the global variable contains the page number of a listing of posts (as in archives).

Core uses a lot of (slightly confusing) globals (so don't blame yourself).

Comment: Hey, thanks. So what exactly am I doing wrong? I still need proper pagination in my blog, and assumed that `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` would work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code (which is basically the same as yours) but it did not work for me when using WP_Query($args).

```
if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) > 1) { 
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); 
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) > 1) { 
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); 
} else { 
    $paged = 1; 
}
```

Although it's not recommended, pagination began working for me when I changed WP_Query($args) to query_posts($args) and then adjusted The Loop accordingly.

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; }

$args_main = array(
    'cat'               => $my_categories_variable,
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'paged'             => $paged
);

query_posts($args_main);
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
```

**NOTE:**

As Kaiser noted in his comment below query_posts() can screw things up. At the very least reset the query after The Loop.

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Please, don't recommend using `query_posts()`. It's an internal funciton that shouldn't be used as it overrides the `global $wp_query` and disconnects it from `$wp_the_query`. Which means you just destabilized your whole system and ever second query will break somewhere hidden. Have fun debugging that.

Comment: Thank you. I am avoiding query_posts at all costs, which is why I'm swapping my code to WP_Query (hence my problem now).